# Is there a simple way of making the gradle sonar task from the sonarqube plugin call execute the check task first for multi module test coverage?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, multi-module

I'm trying to set up a simple build with Gradle (Kotlin DSL), but I am stuck writing the sonar task configuration: it seems that no matter what I do, the task won't execute the check task first.

In my setup, since check calls all the subprojects test tasks, I have test depend on the javadoc generation, and jacoco test report depend on test, for every submodule, but when I call the main project build sonar task, which depends on the check task, javadoc is not generated, tests are not executed, and jacoco reports are not created, thus resulting in sonarqube local instance showing 0% coverage.

`java-common-conventions.gradle.kts`, used in the two subprojects gradle build.

```
plugins {
    // Java support
    java
    // Tests JaCoCo reports support
    jacoco
}

repositories {
    // Maven repository
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        // Define dependency versions as constraints
        implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0")
    }

    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.1")
}

tasks.javadoc {
    setDestinationDir(file("$rootDir/docs/javadoc/${project.name}"))
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    dependsOn(tasks.javadoc)
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport)
}

tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn(tasks.test)
    // Enable xml reports for SonarQube
    reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
    }
}
```

`build.gradle.kts` of the root project (which is empty, only has the two submodules).

```
plugins {
    java
    jacoco
    // SonarQube plugin for code quality analysis
    id("org.sonarqube") version "4.2.1.3168"
}

repositories {
    // Maven repository
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.sonar {
    dependsOn(tasks.check)
}

sonar {
    properties {
        property("sonar.projectName", rootProject.name)
        property("sonar.host.url", project.property("sonar.host.url").toString())
        property("sonar.projectKey", project.property("sonar.projectKey").toString())
        property("sonar.token", project.property("sonar.token").toString())
    }
}
```

I tried using the `subprojects` block with `forEach` iterations over the tasks with type `Test` (changing it in the convention) to add `rootProject.tasks.sonar { dependsOn(it) }` for every subproject test task, tried using `mustRunAfter` (later understanding that's not of use), and other similar variants, still not seeing the sonar task run check and tests before uploading essentially what's a null report.

When I try and call the sonar command (either from Intellij, or `gradle sonar` or `./gradlew sonar`), the jacoco reports are not generated (probably tests don't run either), and this is the output:

```
12:20:23 PM: Executing 'sonar'...

> Task :buildSrc:generateExternalPluginSpecBuilders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:extractPrecompiledScriptPluginPlugins UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compilePluginsBlocks UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:generatePrecompiledScriptPluginAccessors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:generateScriptPluginAdapters UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :buildSrc:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :buildSrc:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
> Task :check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :swarm:compileJava
> Task :simulator:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :simulator:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :simulator:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :simulator:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :swarm:processResources
> Task :swarm:classes
> Task :swarm:compileTestJava

> Task :sonar
Missing blame information for the following files:
[omitted for shorter block, just waiting to stage and commit]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s
15 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 11 up-to-date
12:20:37 PM: Execution finished 'sonar'.
```

I just also wanna specify that the jacoco reports are generated correctly with the check task, and even though they're not aggregated or appended to a single report, sonarqube finds both well.

I seem to understand that if there are some tests from subproject A that cover some parts of subproject B, it's good to aggregate the reports (or simply append everything to the one report): I'm not sure if I will need that, so I would rather keep them separated, but if that's not possible, I'm still open to getting just one big report for the root project.

Comment: The Sonar Gradle Plugin is not a good Gradle citizen and doesn't follow Gradle best practices, so it's not surprising that it's being difficult! What `./gradlew` commands are you running? Can you add the command and the resulting log output to your question?

Comment: @aSemy added in edit, hopefully it's some more useful info, it seems from what I read there that the subprojects get compiled, but the only test task that executes is the root project one (which rightfully so says NO-SOURCE)

Comment: you will find some information here, https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.7/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-gradle/#task-dependencies  , I also spent lots of time to make things work properly in multi-project build. I ended up creating dependencies between `sonar` task and `jacocoTestReport` to make sure test & coverage reports are available to Sonar.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti dammit! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction: I was able to solve this by adding `rootProject.tasks.named("sonar").get().dependsOn(tasks.jacocoTestReport)` to the java common conventions plugin in buildSrc for the multiple projects.